# How do I close my Discord bot after it sends a message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am using a bot to send a message in between a program, utilising it as a function.

```
def sendmessage(message):
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
        CHANNEL_ID = (ID)
        channel = client.get_channel(int(CHANNEL_ID))
        await channel.send(message)
        print("sent")
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

After it sends a message, the bot stays active and the program freezes.
For ease, I have included an example of a program that stops working:

```
print("Hi")
sendmessage("Hello world!")
print("Hi")
```

The second print command doesn't go through as the bot is still active.
How do I shut down the bot so my program keeps on working?

I've tried using `bot.close()` at the end, and it doesn't work.
I've tried using `sys.exit(0)`, and it terminates the entire program, not only the bot.
What I want is for the simplified program to:

1. Say 'Hi'
2. Send a discord message
3. Say 'Hi' again

It gets stuck after step 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason your program gets stuck in a loop is because you didn't close the listener after printing "sent". Try this code:

```
def sendmessage(message):
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
        CHANNEL_ID = (ID)
        channel = client.get_channel(int(CHANNEL_ID))
        await channel.send(message)
        print("sent")
        await client.close()
    client.run(TOKEN)
```